# Save output from process to Network Drive

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

We currently output to our SharePoint 2016 site which can be done via a URL option.
With the advent of SP Online, this is no longer possible, so we are going to output the file to a Network Drive and use MS Flow to push into SP Online.

The Access Database has a lot of processes in it which gather data from various places, calculates and then provides this output at the end.

I am not up to speed on all things VBA, but I cannot find a solution to being able to help me with this.

The current script for this is below, which also deletes the previous file to allow for the new one.
How would I go about updating this to output the file to a Network Drive - `\\ServerName\Team\Reports\SP_Movement\Files_To_SP`

```vb
Private Sub Update_ShP()   'Refreshes report in SharePoint Reports folder


'Code to delete report file from ShP

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim xmlhttp
Dim sharepointUrl, sharepointFileName
Dim aFile, bFile As String
Dim LobjXML As Object

' Parent Sharepoint URL
sharepointUrl = "https://dms.company.com/Reports/"

' Sets the report name we want to remove (BoM Data 1)
aFile = "Q_ATP_OUTPUT.xlsx"

Set LobjXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    sharepointFileName = sharepointUrl & aFile

    ' Removes the data from the server, false means synchronous
    LobjXML.Open "DELETE", sharepointFileName, False

    ' Sends the request to remove the file
    LobjXML.send

  Set LobjXML = Nothing

DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export-Q_ATP_OUTPUT"

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Not clear to me what you need. You want to output a file from where?

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Sharepoint, but even though access doesn't give you access to the vba behind "Export-Q.." couldn't you just use the wizards under the external data tab to re-create the export but save to the new location?

Comment: So the output is from this Access DB process, the VBA deletes the previous file that was exported out and replaces with the current one.